# cordova-plugin-Firebase 0.1.25 "Google Firebase Plugin updated not able to build for Android

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins

I am not able to build for Android due to Firebase update his plugin.

**cordova-plugin-Firebase 0.1.25 "Google Firebase Plugin"**

I tried with remove/add platform for cordova but no luck.
I also tried with downgrade the plugin version to 11.8.0. But not able build.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing same issue with the android build. I have tried following solution for this and It's worked for me. Please try following solution for the above issue

```
  dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        }
```

Add this lines in the platform/android/build.gradle after this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```

It's worked for me.

Thank you.